# Windows Internal Database causing slow performance?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

It seems that Windows Internal Database (MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID) is causing slow performance on our Windows Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Host. It more or less constant using 10-20+% CPU.
Users complain their programs are way to slow.

When I stop Windows Internal Database service then it's running fine again.

There are 7 users on the server, with 2 vCPUs, I've already added one to see if that fixed the performance issue, and 4GB RAM. Maybe I should add 1 or 2 GB?

Remote Desktop Connection Broker is using Windows Internal Database so I can't have it closed too long.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Baseline investigation please. What exactly is slow? Do not guess, look at the performance counters. How does the hardware look?

Comment: "Everything".
User logon, Outlook, Dynamics, switching program.
Hardware is a VMware VM.
I'll see if I can get anything from performance counters.

Comment: I've added 2GB RAM, until now there has not been performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 vCPUs and only 4 GB of RAM? You're likely just starving your clients of resources. Increase *both* vCPUs and RAM to give better performance. Increasing to 4 vCPUs will help free up CPU cycles for your clients' processes.

Most likely, you have something installed on the server that utilizes WID (Sharepoint, for one). Dynamics *might* also use it, but I'm not 100% sure on that one. Either way, splitting the load will help.

Comment: `Most likely, the WID is used by some internal process (like the registry, among other things)` - what does this mean? what does the registry use WID for?

Comment: @MDMarra Oh, I'm silly and clearly need to sleep. Registry was a bad example (because well, it's not a valid example...). Updating my question...

Comment: Remote Desktop Connection Broker is the only thing I can see using WID.

Comment: I had already added an extra vCPU when I saw WID running with 10-20+% CPU, but also the extra RAM seems needed.
There have not been any issues since :-)

Comment: @kimr-dk Yeah, that would do it. 4 GB of RAM is pretty low for a shared server. Then again, I have a 2k3 box with ~30 terminal users on 3.2 GB (the 32-bit limit)...

Comment: Yes, 2012 R2 and Dynamics may be more memory consuming.